# Tabla dinámica excel

Tags: excel, tabla-dinámica, hoja-de-cálculo-tabla-dinámica

yo tengo la siguiente tabla [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero que haciendo una tabla dinámica me quedé así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo hacer?

Comment: No se puede así como lo planteas, sí pones en filas la familia y en columnas los proveedores, lo que podrías hacer es contabilizar a partir de la intersección de familia y provedor y poner 1 si es que ese proveedor te provee la familia y en cero verías cuando no aplica.

Comment: Gracias!!!!!!!!

Comment: @OmarAlvarado transforma tu comentario en respuesta, será de utilidad en futuras consultas. (y de paso puede darte puntos)